# How to code sign my "binaries"? (php scripts)

Tags: code-signing

Can you tell me how to generate a checksum/hash for a .tar archive with a php script of mine that I offer for download? I mainly want this as integrity verification mechanism. Is there any free/simple/alternative way instead of obtaining a code signing certificate (eg Comodo)? Thanks.

Edit: I don't know if this makes any sense/is applicable, but I don't want to sign every file one by one, just the result .tar archive.

Comment: do you want to generate it on the fly? or do you just need to generate the checksum with a command line tool and display it to the user?

Comment: Both are OK, I suppose the second is easier though. I don't care if I manually generate the checksum and post it online. This is what I had in mind anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just generate an sha1 hash of the archive using the unix command line tool `sha1sum filename.tar` or any other program or tool that generates hashes. Then when you offer your file for download also list the output of that command, and once users download the archive they can do the same thing and if the outputs match, the files are the same.

Comment: Is there any tool you have used successfully on Windows?

Comment: http://download.cnet.com/MD5-SHA-1-Checksum-Utility/3000-2092_4-10911445.html looks free and good

Answer (score 3):

Well some open-source projects like the Apache Webserver give out SHA1-sums and additionally release a GPG/PGP signature. You can use [gnupg](http://www.gnupg.org/) for that which is free.

You create a key-pair and share the public-key (on the website or with a key-server like http://pgp.mit.edu/) and keep the private-key on your side. The private-key is used for signing the .tar and your users can then verify the .tar with the public-key.

Comment: is it different from the way this function works? http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php